# How to deal with caseTeamMember Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I have a requirement to add user to case team and need to validate that user should be skilled resource and should have specific skills otherwise do not allow to add that user to case team. I was expecting that trigger on caseTeamMember will work but it seems we can not write trigger on it. Any thoughts, how we can achieve it?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, You can create a custom VF page which will take input from the user to add the members to a case and use it as List button. In the controller, You can validate the details before insert.  Creating CaseTeamMember is allowed through the apex.

Find here more detail about this object:- [CaseTeamMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_caseteammember.htm)

Yes, You are right that salesforce has the limitation as we cannot write trigger for CaseTeamMember object. You are not left with more option as the validation rule is also not allowed.

Comment: Anything on the road-map for a CaseTeamMember trigger? I don't find any documentation around this as a future enhancement. We now officially have AccountTeamMember and OpportunityTeamMember triggers.

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom object, Build a Custom UI to do CRUD on that. Write a trigger to sync it against Case Team Member.